# Python SQLITE Update clause not updating

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to update my database and unsure where ive gone wrong. testing has confirmed that its definitely parsing through the code, when printed all the variables have the values they should have, but for some reason even after commiting no changes are made. Have I missed some simple syntax?

```
c.execute(''' UPDATE Stats SET
              WinAmount = ? ,
              PickAmount = ? ,
              StarPlayerAmount = ? 
              WHERE MapName IS ? AND BrawlerName IS ? '''
              , (NWin , NPick , NStarPlayer ,BattleDetails['event']['map'],winner['brawler']['name']
conn.commit()
```

Edit: I dont get any errors, the database just remains as it was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of the `IS` syntax appears incorrect.  `IS` is mainly used when comparing to `NULL`, not for other types of comparisons.  Try this version:

```
c.execute('''UPDATE Stats SET
    WinAmount = ? ,
    PickAmount = ? ,
    StarPlayerAmount = ? 
    WHERE MapName = ? AND BrawlerName = ? ''',
       (NWin , NPick , NStarPlayer, BattleDetails['event']['map'], winner['brawler']['name']))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that syntax, im fairly new to python and still picking up these sorts of things,but unfortunately this didnt solve the problem

Comment: I dont get an error, but the database doesnt get updated (fetchall still returns [ ] )

Comment: Are you sure that there is a match?

Comment: I did have a failsafe but now that you've brought it up, the error might be in that part of the code. I'll go see if I can figure it out, and if not ill ask. Thanks!

Comment: My failsafe was updating not inserting ‍♂️Thanks for the quick and helpful response!